# When configuring Tomcat 7 HTTPS, then application cannot connect to other HTTPS hosts

Tags: java, tomcat, https, debian

I have a strange problem:
When I configure my tomcat to work over https connection (configuring the connector in server.xml), then my application is not able to connect to other https urls (external api-s).

The error what I get:
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: ...

My connector conf:

```
<Connector
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/home/user/my-https.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

My keystore is a regular keystore containing all the necessary RapidSSL certs.

When I run my tomcat without HTTPS configuration then my app is able to connect to other external API-s that use https.

What I assume here is that when I connect with my application to HTTPS, then the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts should be used as a truststore. But looks like tomcat messes up cacerts and my my-https.keystore at some point. When I run my app on Jetty with the same HTTPS conf, all works.

Has anyone had the same problem or am I doing something literally wrong here?

My environment:
* Debian Wheezy (on AWS);
* Tomcat 7.0.28 (comes with Debian);
* OpenJDK 1.7.0.25

Comment: Never mind. The httpcommons httpclient has some bug in it. Switched over to Jersey Client and everything works now.